# Android Layout on 7'' tablet

Tags: android, tablet

I designed an app for phones and tablets but I have a problem.

I've tested on 10''/7'' tablets and it works fine, but on a 7'' tablets with smallest width = 480.0 it show the layout from the phone.

I have the three folders : layout, layout-sw600dp and layout-sw720dp.

Can you provide me some tips on how to achive that on the 400X800 7'' tablet to enter the tablet layout and not the phone layout?

Many Thanks.

Comment: dp is not a measure of physical size! Delete this question. Read this thread **thoroughly** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android then if it's still not clear, come back and ask a more detailed question

Answer (score 2):

Faced same issue . No need to create 3 different layout folder . 
Use [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) logic. Get your device height & weight . Set layout height & width respect to device height & width(Apply % rule) .

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

   int DeviceTotalWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
   int DeviceTotalHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
```

And set this way,

```
 LinearLayout  LL_First_Section=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Your_Id);
 LL_First_Section.getLayoutParams().height= (int) (DeviceTotalHeight*11.21/100);
```

Comment: Hello, but what means 11.21 -> I've added in my code this and now the layout for tablet enters on my phone which has DeviceTotalWidth 1440 and DeviceTotalHeight 2392

Comment: 11.21 % of total screen heigh. This way is most accurate

Comment: You can change this as per your requirement.

Comment: @davinci.2405 Did you understand what i say ?

Comment: Just a second to test it on both phone and tablet

Comment: @davinci.2405 Waiting for your response .